# Jmeter assertions on random controller

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Will there be a difference in results when we add response assertion, duration assertion to controllers instead of thread?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "thread" is in your world, but Assertions obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so you can apply one or more assertions to:

- a single [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)
- several Samplers
- all Samplers in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
- all Samplers in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

Here is the image from the [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) article showing how do scoping rules work:

[image]